# Scrapyd Deploy was not successful

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

My Scrapy.cfg file is

```
[deploy:scra]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = project2

[deploy:scrapyd2]
url = http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/
project = project1
```

If I do below command means its throws an error which is given below.

```
$ scrapy deploy -l
scra                 http://localhost:6800/
scrapyd2             http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/
$ scrapyd-deploy -l
scra                 http://localhost:6800/
scrapyd2             http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/

$ scrapy deploy scra
    Packing version 1412570503
    Deploying to project "project2" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
    Server response (200):
    {"status": "error", "message": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'eggs'"}

$ scrapyd-deploy scra -p project2
Packing version 1412571000
Deploying to project "project2" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'eggs'"}
```

So how can I deploy my scrapy project through scrapyd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. For me sudo works fine. Try:

```
sudo scrapy deploy scra
```